# IE 10 Compatibility Problems

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I'm building my portfolio site with Twitter bootstrap and when I'm using the code to create a div box within an image gallary, so far it looks fine in Firefox and Google Chrome, however, in Internet Explorer, my images are blown up huger and the images go downwards instead of on a side-to-side fashion. When I mean my images expand huger, they expand huger than original.

Here is the CSS code I am using (This code is used to create my css div picture box) :

```
body {
    background:#F5F3F0;
    color:#555;
    font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;    
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 0;
}

.colnode {
    height: 100%;
    width: 215px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.colnodefull {
    height: 200px;
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px -5px 0px 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#colnodemug {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;   
}
.container2 {
    width:1335px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: -130px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #cdcdcd;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 20px #cdcdcd;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 20px #cdcdcd;
}

#middle {
        overflow: auto;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
}

middle img {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

div.scroller {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 930px;
        position: inherit;
}

/*div.scroller*/ div.section {
        float:left;
        height: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding: 80px 0 10px 245px;
        width:700px;
        font-size: 10pt;
}

div.scroller div.content {
        width:20000px;
}

div#section {
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
}

div.controls {
        height: 600px;
        width: 230px;
        float: left;
        margin: 80px -5px 0px 15px;
        position: fixed;
}

div.controls a:hover {
        /*border-bottom: 5px #99cccc solid;
        opacity:.5;*/
}
```

And here is the HTML code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
  <html lang="en">   
  <head>   
  <meta charset="utf-8">   
  <title>Greg's Portfolio</title>   
  <meta name="description" content="Greg's Portfolio Website">  
  <link href="css/twitter-bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/column.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">   
  .container {  
  margin-top: 200px;  
  margin-right: -400px;
  }  
  </style>  
  </head> 
  <h1>Greg's Portfolio</h1>  
  <body>  
  <div class="container">  
  <div class="row">  
  <div class="span6">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
        <li><a href="homepage.htm">Home</a></li>  
        <li><a href="about_me.htm">About Me</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact_me.htm">Contact Me</a></li>
  </div>  
  </div>  
  </div>    
  </body>
  <body>
<div class="container2">
<div class="colnodemug">
  <a href="good_lust_chuck_description.htm"><img src="images/Life_Webpage.png" width="300px" height="300px"/></a>
  <a href="how_high_description.htm"><img src="images/how_high.jpg" width="300px" height="300px"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a tip: Don't code against Firefox and Chrome and hack the shit out of your site until it works well with IE. Follow the standards and develop for IE. I've used this approach since day one and I never have compatibility issues with any browser. When you leave IE out this is what happens.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `<body>`'s?

Comment: or here's a tip: develop with web standards. then fill in the gaps for lesser browsers, typically ies. you can start developing for ie, but if your support goes back to 6, that is certainly one way to do it, but not the standards way

Comment: like @aeron said you have two bodys. your h1 is in your head or somewhere. and you are declaring the images units in the attribute, you dont need that. validate your markup when things don't work and you'll be surprised how fast things start to work

Comment: You can find the Validator at: http://validator.w3.org/ - As @albert suggests, it's very helpful.

Comment: cannot stress validation enough with n00bs...lots of times i don't get the message across, or they don't want to listen/learn. point is, validation is merely a tool to ease your pain. use it. every time. all the time. it's not really about 100% validation every time either. the validator's true power appears once you understand it and how browsers/user agents work differently. then you can break validation to accomplish your goals. these are ok breaks, you know why you are doing them. and we are adults. doesn't have to validate 100% of the time.